# How to make a 4d plot using Python with matplotlib

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib

I am looking for a way to create four-dimensional plots (surface plus a color scale) using Python and matplotlib.  I am able to generate the surface using the first three variables, but I am not having success adding the color scale for the fourth variable.  Here is a small subset of my data below.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Data Subset

```
var1    var2    var3    var4
10.39   73.32   2.02    28.26
11.13   68.71   1.86    27.83
12.71   74.27   1.89    28.26
11.46   91.06   1.63    28.26
11.72   85.38   1.51    28.26
13.39   78.68   1.89    28.26
13.02   68.02   2.01    28.26
12.08   64.37   2.18    28.26
11.58   60.71   2.28    28.26
8.94    65.67   1.92    27.04
11.61   59.57   2.32    27.52
19.06   74.49   1.69    63.35
17.52   73.62   1.73    63.51
19.52   71.52   1.79    63.51
18.76   67.55   1.86    63.51
19.84   53.34   2.3     63.51
20.19   59.82   1.97    63.51
17.43   57.89   2.05    63.38
17.9    59.95   1.89    63.51
18.97   57.84   2       63.51
19.22   57.74   2.05    63.51
17.55   55.66   1.99    63.51
19.22   101.31  6.76    94.29
19.41   99.47   6.07    94.15
18.99   94.01   7.32    94.08
19.88   103.57  6.98    94.58
19.08   95.38   5.66    94.14
20.36   100.43  6.13    94.47
20.13   98.78   7.37    94.47
20.36   89.36   8.79    94.71
20.96   84.48   8.33    94.01
21.02   83.97   6.78    94.72
19.6    95.64   6.56    94.57
```

Comment: Sorry, the data did not format properly.  It should read:

Comment: var1 10.39
11.13
12.71
11.46
11.72
13.39
13.02
12.08
11.58
8.94
11.61
19.06
17.52
19.52
18.76
19.84
20.19
17.43
17.9
18.97
19.22
17.55
19.22
19.41
18.99
19.88
19.08
20.36
20.13
20.36
20.96
21.02
19.6

Comment: var2 73.32
68.71
74.27
91.06
85.38
78.68
68.02
64.37
60.71
65.67
59.57
74.49
73.62
71.52
67.55
53.34
59.82
57.89
59.95
57.84
57.74
55.66
101.31
99.47
94.01
103.57
95.38
100.43
98.78
89.36
84.48
83.97
95.64

Comment: var3 2.02
1.86
1.89
1.63
1.51
1.89
2.01
2.18
2.28
1.92
2.32
1.69
1.73
1.79
1.86
2.3
1.97
2.05
1.89
2
2.05
1.99
6.76
6.07
7.32
6.98
5.66
6.13
7.37
8.79
8.33
6.78
6.56

Comment: var4 28.26
27.83
28.26
28.26
28.26
28.26
28.26
28.26
28.26
27.04
27.52
63.35
63.51
63.51
63.51
63.51
63.51
63.38
63.51
63.51
63.51
63.51
94.29
94.15
94.08
94.58
94.14
94.47
94.47
94.71
94.01
94.72
94.57

Comment: Chris, instead of adding comments, can you edit your post? To make the data come out as you expect, use the code formatting (highlight it and press the button that looks like curly brackets). Also, post what code you have so far. You're much more likely to get a good response if you do so.

Comment: Have you tried looking at [this](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo.html) link?  The screenshots and thumbnails are a really good way to learn about matplotlib's capabilities.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(python) plot 3d surface with colormap as 4th dimension, function of x,y,z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32461452/python-plot-3d-surface-with-colormap-as-4th-dimension-function-of-x-y-z)

Answer (score 16):

To create the plot you want, we need to use matplotlib's `plot_surface` to plot `Z` vs `(X,Y)` surface, and then use the keyword argument `facecolors` to pass in a new color for each patch.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm

# create some fake data
x = y = np.arange(-4.0, 4.0, 0.02)
# here are the x,y and respective z values
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = np.sinc(np.sqrt(X*X+Y*Y))
# this is the value to use for the color
V = np.sin(Y)

# create the figure, add a 3d axis, set the viewing angle
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.view_init(45,60)

# here we create the surface plot, but pass V through a colormap
# to create a different color for each patch
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, facecolors=cm.Oranges(V))
```

[image]

Comment: How do you use the `Axes3D` from `mpl_toolkits.mplot3d`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting a weird error when trying to set the facecolors manually:

```
raise ValueError("RGBA sequence should have length 3 or 4")
ValueError: RGBA sequence should have length 3 or 4
```

My data set is 717x26 and the shapes of x, y, z, and fcolors are (26,717), (26,717), (26,717), and (26,717,4). As far as I understood the facecolors property, the shape should be fine.

The code for plotting is given here:

```
# mesh the x-y coodrdinates
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# Create a 3D plot
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

# Creat the mapper for the 4D
mapper = cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap='viridis')
mapper.set_array([])

# Map the data to RGBA values
fcolors = mapper.to_rgba(np.transpose(WSS))

# Output the dimensions
print('fcolors: ',fcolors.shape,', x, y, z: ',x.shape,' - ',y.shape,' - ',np.transpose(z).shape)

# Plot the surface incl. the 4th dimension
surf = ax.plot_surface(x, y, np.transpose(z), facecolor=fcolors)
```

Does anybody know why I'm getting the RGBA error in that case?
All the examples provided above work without problems.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35116880)