# How to make a Scatter Plot for a Dataset with 4 Attribtues and 5th attribute being the Cluster

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

I have a dataset which looks like this,

[image]

It has four attributes and the fifth column (which I added by myself) is the cluster of each row to which the row belongs.

I want to build something like a **Scatter Plot** for this dataset, but I am unable to do so. I have tried searching it up and the best I could find was this following question on Stackoverflow,

[How to make a 4d plot with matplotlib using arbitrary data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995610/how-to-make-a-4d-plot-with-matplotlib-using-arbitrary-data)

Using this, I was able to make a Scatter Plot but it can only be done for **three attributes** while fourth attribute being the **cluster** of each row.

Can anyone help me figure out how would it be possible to do the same to make a **Scatter Plot** for a dataset similar to mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend something like seaborn's [`pairplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html):

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.pairplot(df, hue="cluster")
```

See the images in the link, of what it looks like.
This creates several pairwise scatterplots instead of trying to make a 3D plot and arbitrarily flatten one of the dimensions.